# Why it goes into the right branch when wrong hash name is called?

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm new in learning Ruby.In following code ,I made a mistake,writing a wrong word '`hash`' instead of '`movies`'.But I find it also goes into the right way .WHY this happened 
?Could someone explain for me?

```
movies = {:Frozen => 9}
puts "input a movie title:"
title = gets.chomp
puts "the rating of the movie:"
rating = gets.chomp
if hash[title.to_i].nil?  #here,i wrote 'hash' instead of 'movies'
  movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
  puts "Added successfully!"
else
  puts "The movie already exists."
end
```

These are my inputs and the running results:

Why `hash[title.to_i]` seems be no-nil and still puts out '`The movie already exists.`' ?

```
input a movie title:
Frozen
the rating of the movie:
4
The movie already exists.
```

Comment: `title.to_i` - what's the logic behind this?

Comment: Oh and btw, method `hash` exists on all objects.

Comment: Right, I think it's calling `hash` on `main`, which returns a `Fixnum`, and then it's doing an integer offset into that `Fixnum`, which returns a non-nil value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `hash`method of `main`

```
p self  # => main
p self.methods.sort #=> [:!, :!=, :! ... :hash,...]
p self.hash # => -1928951575263865998
```